# How to do this equivalent C# OOP in python?

Tags: c#, python

I need following structure in python.

```
public class Circle
{

    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;

    public Circle(member1)
    {
      this.member1 = member1;
      initializeRest();    
    }

    private intializeRest()
    {

        //do lot of computation to get result1 & result2
        this.member2 = result2;
        this.member3 = result2;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class Circle:
   def __init__(self, member1):
      self.member1=member1
      self.rest()

   def rest(self):
      self.member2=result2
      self.member3=result2
```

Comment: You could inherit from `object` to get a new-style class even in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have enforced private anything; the convention for letting others know that a method/function/class/what-have-you is private is to prefix it with a single leading underscore.  Third-party programs can use this, such as auto-documenting systems, and help() in IDLE, to ignore such _names.

Your code would translate like this:

```
class Circle(object):              # in Python 3 you don't need `object`
    member1 = None                 # not needed since all three are initialized
    member2 = None                 # in __init__, but if you had others that
    member3 = None                 # weren't this is how you would do it
    def __init__(self, member1):
        self.member1=member1
        self._rest()
    def _rest(self):
        # lots of computing....
        self.member2=result2
        self.member3=result2
```

Given your comments in the code, though, you would be just as well off to make `_rest` be part of `__init__`...

```
class Circle(object):              # in Python 3 you don't need `object`
    def __init__(self, member1):
        self.member1=member1
        # lots of computing....
        self.member2=result2
        self.member3=result2
```